# Map array into array of objects where for one element of array we may have multiple objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Convert array of objects and array like `[[{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}],{e:5}]` to single array of objects like `[{a:1},{b:2},{c:3},{d:4},{e:5}]` in javascript in optimal way.
I used spread operator to flatten the array but `{...[{a:1,b:2}] }` gave `{0:{a:1},1:{b:2}}`which is adding extra key. Then I removed the key by iterating for all elements. Please help me with optimal solution.

Comment: Will it ever be nested doubly or more?

Comment: Can you show your effort so far?

Answer (score 1):

Shortest

```js
var data = [[{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}],{e:5}];
var result = [].concat(...data).reduce((ac,a) => 
  ac.concat(Object.keys(a).map( k=>({[k]:a[k]}) )) ,[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array#reduce` to flatten your array. Then, use `array#reduce` to get the individual key-value pair pair using `array#map`.

```js
var data = [[{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}],{e:5}];

var getObject = (data) => {
  return data
  .reduce((r, b) =>  r.concat(b), [])
  .reduce((r,o) => r.concat(Object.keys(o).map(k => ({[k] : o[k]}))),[]);
}
console.log(getObject(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the arrays using [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), combine to a single object by spreading into [Object#assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), get the [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) them to the requested form:

```js
const data = [[{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}],{e:5}];

const result = Object.entries(
    Object.assign({}, ...[].concat(...data))
  ).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check for an array and take a recursive approach for this case. If not map the entries for objects with a single property.

```js
var data = [[{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { c: 3, d: 4 }], { e: 5 }],
    result = data.reduce(function fn(r, a) {
        return r.concat(Array.isArray(a)
            ? a.reduce(fn, [])
            : Object.entries(a).map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
        );
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
console.log([[{a:1,b:2},{c:3,d:4}],{e:5}].
reduce((arr, element) => Array.isArray(element) ? [...arr, ...element] : [...arr, element], []).
reduce((arr, element) => [...arr, ...Object.entries(element).map(([key, value]) => ({[key]: value}))], []));
```